# CSS media query does not work

Tags: css

Hello stackoverflow community! I need help with @media query. I've added:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    .logo-nam-text {
        font-size: 50px;
    }
}
```

To my style.css but it doesn't work, what am I doing wrong? Should I create new file with that query? What if I want to use it in the same stylesheet?

Comment: Can you post the full code in style.css. Any demo of the page?

Comment: are you sure you need `max-device-width` and not `max-width` ?

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli LOL thanx!!!! write into answers.

Comment: You can also just go with @media (max-width: 480px) {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use `max-width` instead of `max-device-width`.